# Setting a keyboard shortcut to paste a specified text

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

How can i set a keyboard shortcut to paste a specified text always? ( windows 7)
I want to specify my password to a keyboard shortcut to use in logins.

Comment: Try something like FingerTips if you really want to. But it's not secure at all, so I suggest you use a password manager instead (e.g. Lastpass).

Comment: If you use voice recognition software [Dragon NaturallySpeaking](http://www.nuance.com/dragon/index.htm) (Windows/Mac, non-free), you can create a voice command to paste some text, it's straightforward to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org)

You can use AutoHotKey to bind any key combination to perform an action. In case of pasting text, you can use the `Send` command. Here is an example:

```
#g::Send p4ssw0rd
```

Save the above command in an `ahk` file and run. The hotkey <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> now binds to the string `p4ssw0rd`. You can learn how to further configure the hotkeys in [the tutorial](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Tutorial.htm)

Note that  this is not a safe way to store your passwords, since anyone using your computer could paste them in any text field.