# Setting up Keyboard Shortcuts to paste text Linux

Tags: linux, open-source, keyboard-shortcuts

I am looking for the same solution as [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13631/setting-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-paste-a-specified-text).

I am doing some editing where I need to paste the same base text over and over and modify them a little. The problem is I have two such texts which I need to paste alternatively. So right now I am copying each time and pasting them. I would very much like it if the texts can be assigned to different shortcut keys and pasted without having to copy them each time.

But I don't use windows. I want a solution in Linux.

Is it possible? I would like FOSS, if possible. If I can configure the keyboard shortcut myself without needing any special software, it would be even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might wish to take a look at **[Glipper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glipper)**. Apart from being a "normal clipboard manager", it also supports plugins. According to the linked Wikipedia page, one of those plugins is:

> A snippet plugin, which lets the user access text snippets they want to use very frequently

At least on Ubuntu, this plugin seems to be installed along Glipper automatically (being reported as part of the [glipper package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/lucid/i386/glipper/filelist) at least with Lucid, which is not the "youngest version"). Same [applies to Debian](https://packages.debian.org/sid/sh4/glipper/filelist).

You can find out more about it at [the project's Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/glipper). Or by reading [this review](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2011/10/a-useful-clipboard-manager-for-ubuntu-glipper/).

[image: Glipper plugins]
<sup>Glipper plugins (source: [Hectic Geek](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2011/10/a-useful-clipboard-manager-for-ubuntu-glipper/); click image for larger variant)</sup>

Not using it myself, I cannot say how exactly those "Snippets" are pasted, and whether you freely can assign hotkeys to them. *Glipper* is available for free, and falls under the [GNU Lesser General Public License](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License) (aka LGPL) – a close relative to the GPL allowing non-GPL projects to use its code (basically "GPL without copyleft") – so yes, that makes it FOSS.

Comment: I would like to bind a specific piece of text to a key so I can just paste it. Glipper saves my copy history from which I have to select and paste each time I want

Comment: That's what Glipper itself does, yes. For snippets, you would need to enable (and set up) its "Snippets" plugin, see the screenshot; seems that's disabled by default. I cannot check/try that currently, as I'm not near any Linux desktop.

Comment: the snippets option in Glipper, keeps the code pieces stored and when I click it moves that particular piece of code to the top of the clipboard. However either it does not have assigning shortcut keys or I don't know how to assign. There does not seem to be a way. Other than that, Glipper is good. Can you suggest something?

Comment: I'm not using any snippet manager currently, so unfortunately that's all I can say, sorry.

Comment: It's ok, I will accept the answer for now as it really helped me in my work. But if you find a better solution please come back and post it and message me. Thank up I very much for your timely help

Comment: Thanks, @CRags! If I happen to see something, I'll hopefully remember to update my answer accordingly (or post a second one). If somebody else is faster, you can always "move your acceptance" to a better answer of course ;)